# How to override/replace microsoft essential encoder file?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, expression-encoder, expression-encoder-sdk

Using encoder ([Link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Expression.Encoder/)), To record video which is playing on screen for Selenium automation script.

```
 ScreenCaptureJob scj = new ScreenCaptureJob();
 scj.OutputScreenCaptureFileName = "XXX.avi";
 scj.Start();
```

It is required to delete existing file, before to write .avi file on existing name.

Is it possible to replace existing file Or override it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try deletion of file before saving it:

```
try {
    Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get("PATH TO FILE\"XXX.avi"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving direction. I used to implement with reference to C# utility.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to C# utility, Implemented as:

```
if (File.Exists(path))
{
File.Delete(path);
}
```